# Azure app authentication with Sandbox account returns "unauthorized_client: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers." error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, sandbox

I have a registered Azure app that is working in Microsoft production API. I've created a sandbox test account (according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/sandbox?view=bingads-13) instruction) and I'm trying to receive an OAuth token. According to the instruction I've changed the login endpoint and result link is

```
https://login.windows-ppe.net/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=4abdfe32-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-510dd884cd81&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fads.microsoft.com%2Fmsads.manage&state=12345
```

The problem is when I'm opening this link and trying to login with the created Sandbox account (xxxxxxxxxxxxx@outlook-int.com) it shows me `unauthorized_client` error:

```
We're unable to complete your request

unauthorized_client: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.
```

Supported account type for this application is any Azure AD and personal.

Any ideas what is wrong or what I've missed in my connection with Sanbox account (this happens with Sandbox account only)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, I too got **same error** when I used registered application Client ID and ran below login endpoint in browser:

```
https://login.windows-ppe.net/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=0f949c66-6790-xxxxxxxxxxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fads.microsoft.com%2Fmsads.manage&state=12345
```

[image]

As mentioned in this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/authentication-oauth-quick-start?view=bingads-13#quick-start-sandbox),

> To authenticate in the sandbox environment you **don't need** to register an application. Just use the public "Tutorial Sample App" client ID i.e., **4c0b021c-00c3-4508-838f-d3127e8167ff**.

To resolve the error, make use of below login endpoint by replacing **ClientID** and **redirect URI** values to authenticate with sandbox account like this:

```http
https://login.windows-ppe.net/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=4c0b021c-00c3-4508-838f-d3127e8167ff&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://login.windows-ppe.net/common/oauth2/nativeclient&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20profile%20https://api.ads.microsoft.com/msads.manage%20offline_access&state=12345
```

[image]

When I logged in with sandbox test account, I got **consent screen** with permissions:

[image]

After accepting the above consent, I got **`code`** value in address bar successfully like this:

[image]